# Process multi camera streams in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I'm playing multiple camera streams on raspberry pi4.
But in order to put low stress the CPU , i want to read the frames alternatively from both the videos.
So for example only odd frames of first video are displayed , and even frames of second video are displayed.

```
Ist iteration : frame1 of video 1, Nothing
Second iteration: nothing, frame2 of video2
Third iteration : frame3 of video1, Nothing
Fourth Iteration : Nothing, frame4 of video2
```

The purpose is to put less stress on RPI4 and eventually scale it to play 6 videos.

The code below , for simplification, shows local video files. I'm able to play only first video, but second video hangs right from the start. If I remove the line %3==0 , only then the second video plays.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
names = ['C:/Users/viv/test.mp4', 'C:/Users/viv/parking_lot_1.mp4'];
window_titles = ['first', 'second']
cap = [cv2.VideoCapture(i) for i in names]
frames = [None] * len(names);
gray = [None] * len(names);
ret = [None] * len(names);

while True:
    for i,c in enumerate(cap):
        #print (i)
        if c is not None:
            
            if (c.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)%2==0) & i==0:
                ret[i], frames[i] = c.read();
            elif (c.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)%3==0) & i==1:
                ret[i], frames[i] = c.read();
                print(i,c.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))

    for i,f in enumerate(frames):
        if ret[i] is True:
            gray[i] = cv2.cvtColor(f, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            cv2.imshow(window_titles[i], gray[i]);
           
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

for c in cap:
    if c is not None:
        c.release();
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What's the idea behind the whole if and elif with CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES? Shouldnt already "for i,c in enumerate(cap)" alternate between both devices? Just c.read() and if successful imshow and waitKey in the most inner loop. However take about framedrops if you switch from video files to livestreams.If you have an encoded stream you may not let frames drop.

Comment: Ok. Do you know a method to read only the present frame on demand from the rtsp stream ? So as to not tax the cpu. I don't need real-time video, I just need a single frame every 5th second. That's it

Comment: in many kind of encoded streams, to read a full image you will have to wait for the next keyframe. To my knowledge, opencv doesnt support keyframe-only capturing.